# foreman development vs production (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, foreman

what is the "foreman way" for behaving differently in production vs
development?  That is we want foreman start to start up a bunch of
stuff in dev, however in heroku production we don't need it to start
(for example) solr.

Answer (score 22):

I follow the convention;

- `Procfile` defines *all* processes
- `.foreman` set specific foreman variables

Development:

- `.env` sets environment variables for each developer
- `.env.example` sets defaults for development
- `foreman start` starts all processes

Production:

- `heroku config` sets environment variables
- `heroku ps:scale` turns on or off whichever processes are needed for production

Here's an example from a project.

Procfile:

```
web:    bundle exec unicorn_rails -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

.env.example:

```
# default S3 bucket
S3_KEY=keykeykeykeykeykey
S3_SECRET=secretsecretsecret
S3_BUCKET=myapp-development
```

.env

```
# developer's private S3 bucket
S3_KEY=mememememememememe
S3_SECRET=mysecretmysecret
S3_BUCKET=myapp-development
```

.foreman:

```
# development port is 3000
port: 3000
```

Answer (score 3):

Foreman takes arguments to use a different file (-d) and arguments to specify what to run. It also supports a `.foreman` file that allows those args to become default. See http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

I've used environment-specific `Procfile`s before, which is pretty simple and works fine.

Basically you have `Procfile.development`, `Procfile.production`, etc. In each you can customize the procs you want to start, then run them via `foreman` like so:

```
foreman start -f Procfile.development
```

Another approach is to reference scripts in your `Procfile`, and within each script start up the appropriate process based on the environment. [The creator of Foreman does this](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/358#issuecomment-17556894) and has [an example from his Anvil project your reference](https://github.com/ddollar/anvil/blob/master/bin/web).

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to use a separate job type in our Procfile for dev vs. production.  It is not the most DRY method, but it works...

```
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
sidekiq-prod: bundle exec sidekiq -e production
```

Then we run foreman specifying the prod job on the production system:

```
foreman start -c sidekiq-prod=4
```